# Firefox's searchbox clears as I type

Tags: firefox

About 30% of the time, when I click on the searchbox and type in a query, it clears everything I typed half way through.  For example, if I type "super user", it will clear at "super " so all I see is "user".  It seems like something is stuck, but I'm not sure what.  It doesn't always happen, but it seems that the auto-suggestions feature is also broken..it never works.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.4.  Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Here's my version info:
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100423 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this behaviour in Ubuntu 9.10. Figure it's a bug, and haven't yet researched how to fix it permanently. But as an immediate fix, try opening a text editor and typing there briefly. Now switch back to Firefox and the issue may be resolved. For now...

Answer (score 0):

it tabs away from the field when you aren't looking, don't ask me why.

You load it, it starts, you begin typing (probably looking down at the keyboard), then it pops to the URL field, so you sometimes end up with Super in the Search, and User in the URL entry field.

That happens to me all the time, check and see if that's what's happening to you?